# GSA return symbol ? for double quote

Tags: google-search-appliance

I am getting gsa search result as xml and then parse xml to show the result along with other contents.

I have noticed that double quote(") or special character are returned as question mark (?). I tested using postman on chrome , that xml looks correct.
I am using restTemplate to fetch result.
My code snippets looks as follows

String gsaSearchUrl = "http://xxx.yyy.com/search?client=maintenance_frontend&filter=0&getfields=*&q=frequent&site=default_collection&start=0&num=10&sort=date:D:L:d1";

```
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        MediaType mediaType = new MediaType("application", "xml", Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        headers.setContentType(mediaType);

        //search(gsaSearchUrl);
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        ResponseEntity<GSP> response = restTemplate.exchange(gsaSearchUrl, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<String>(headers), GSP.class);


        gsp = response.getBody();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're query string is encoded before it's sent to GSA? So for example, the query param "sort" should look like the following:

sort=date%3AD%3AL%3Ad1